# Hompage showing page from different theme

Tags: homepage

EDIT: [SOLVED] Page was cached on server, I went to c-panel and purged cach for domain and now it works fine.

I've been banging my head with this one for hours, so any help is welcome.

I have a new wordpress install. I've added a theme [Illdy](https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/illdy/) and I've imported dummy content via [Illdy Companion](https://wordpress.org/plugins/illdy-companion/). After some time working on the theme, I've noticed that while logged out homepage doesn't show any changes but displays dummy content.

So I deleted all plugins and theme and went back to twenty seventeen, but it still displayed dummy content on homepage, in plain html since the theme was removed.
Then I reinstalled whole wordpress, found a new theme and it now displays twenty seventeen on homepage while logged out.

In short all changes to the website are visible while logged in, and when I logout it shows homepage from different source.

If you go to [website homepage](http://arnosplace.net/) you will see twenty seventeen, and if you go to any other [page](http://arnosplace.net/uncategorized/hello-world/) you will see another theme [Sydney](https://wordpress.org/themes/sydney/).

There are no plugins for caching.

Comment: could be a browser cache issue

Comment: The issue is same on different browsers and computers. Tried Ctrl+F5 in chrome, doesn't work. Also tried clearing browsing history, cookies, site data, image and files in chrome, still the problem is same.

Comment: Check with your host, too. They might be caching or using a CDN or something.

Comment: It was cached on server, I went to c-panel and purged cach for domain and now it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, have you checked the home page settings in the admin?

under settings->reading there is an option to set the homepage.

per comments discussion was server caching

Comment: Yes. Changing betweeen static page and latest posts does affect homepage while logged in. But has no effect while logged out, it still displays page from twenty seventeen.

Comment: your header shows a x-proxy-cache HIT response, you could be serving up the page from the server's cache, not the browser cache. I didn't see cloudflare or one of the DNS options, but that can also cause caching issues. Try flushing the nginx cache and see if that helps.

Comment: It also looks like you need to change the front page in the settings for the theme itself under general [illdy support](https://colorlib.com/wp/support/illdy/)

Comment: It was cached on server, I went to c-panel and purged cach for domain and now it works fine. Thanks alot for your help, I wouldn't be able to fix it without you.

I've deleted Illdy few hours ago.